# Numbers on my RAM sticks that come after clock speed

Tags: memory

I have some Buffered, ECC and Registered sticks here.

They're all "1GB 2Rx8 PC2-3200R-333" sticks (a few are 1Rx4 btw), but some of them have different strings following the "333" bit.

- One stick says "1GB **2Rx8** PC2-3200R-333-**10-B1**"  Another says
- "1GB **2Rx8** PC2-3200R-333-**11-H0**"  And another set (of 20)
- sticks says "1GB **1Rx4** PC2-3200R-333-**12**"

When I put these into my computer the system reported a memory mismatch error, so I'd like to know what's compatible with what.

Thanks.

Comment: What motherboard do you have?

Comment: It's a set of blade Dell servers - I recently purchased a shedload of compatible RAM from a computer disposal firm, but clearly some RAM is more compatible than others.

Comment: Only the set of 20 is compatible with one another.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit contradictory when you say they are all 2Rx8 modules but then you go on to say that some are 1Rx4. Assuming that is not a typo, you've got DRAM ranking issues and you need to RTFM for your motherboard to determine what combinations of memory you can run.

Comment: Sorry, yes. All but a few of the sticks are 2Rx8, but there are a few 1Rx4.

Comment: The answer is the same, read the manual to determine what sticks you can use, you should not be mixing and matching.